# Tab Switching freezes (setAdapter)

Tags: java, android, adapter, android-tablayout

I have problem : tabLayout with 3 tabs, 2 last of this have recyclerview.

When i press second tab or third, i have some freezes, because all of this tabs have recylerview, that have adapter.

I debug the app and understood that the app freezes on this row: `setAdapter(adapter)`, how can i fix this?

For tablayout i use `FragmentPagerAdapter` (preloading next tab and save prev)

Thanks, sorry for my english

Example screen:

[image]

Comment: Do you use slide animations when switching tabs? If so, you might be doing too much work simultaneously on the main thread..

Comment: i use viewpager, when i'm slide tabs, i havent freezes; only when i clicked on tabs with recyclerview, all operations working in background thread with rxjava2, but setAdapter no and it's a problem

Comment: I mean that the RecyclerView rendering and the slide effect are heavy on the UI. Since you can only perform UI related operations on the UI thread, a background thread will not help you more than it already has. You can try call the `setAdapter()` method with a small delay (500ms or 1000ms) and see if it improves the behaviour. Another option is to not 'lazy load' the tabs fragments...

Comment: You can also try to disable the slide animation when selecting tabs by using the `setCurrentItem` like this - `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false);`

Comment: There is possibility that you are performing some operation/s on UI thread which should go in background but without code we can continue guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Too late but I will give my answer anyway,
Try to use FragmentStateAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter.
I hope this solves your problem.